# How to connect PIC32MX470F512L to a micro usb connector?

Tags: pic, usb, microchip

I've seen some schematics and the D+ and D- of pic seem to be connected directly to the - and + of the micro usb connector.

As the micro usb has a power of +5, i'm not that confident that it would be ok, because the pic(PIC32MX470F512L) in this case is working at 3V3.

In yours opinion will it be ok to connect directly or opto couplers need to be used?

Another question i would like to ask is if - and + of USB is unidirectional or bidirectional? (I'm asking this because i plan on using opto-couplers)

[image]

Comment: Why do you need an opto-coupler? This might mess up the rise/fall time of the signals. The signals are differential, meaning that they are bi-directional and complimentary (when + is high, - is low and vice-versa). Instead of opto-couplers, you should be using TVS diodes on the lines to protect the device from transient voltages. You should not be using an optocoupler though.

Answer (score 2):

As with so many things in electronics, you start with background knowledge and add the specifics of whatever you are dealing with.

In your case, [background includes understanding how USB works.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB)

The "Signaling" section of the wikipedia article explains that the signals are bidirectional and differential.  This scuppers your idea of using optoisolators.

The signal **levels** are also defined, and have little to nothing to do with the 5V power present on the cable - it therefore doesn't matter to the **signals** whether your PIC operates at 3.3V or 5V.

The next stop is the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/60001185g.pdf) for the chip you want to use.

Page 114 shows you that it has built in hardware for USB.  Anything you just randomly add will interfere with its proper operation.

Page 114:

[image]

Page 113 of the datasheet refers you to Section 27. “USB On-TheGo (OTG)”  (DS60001126) of the PIC documentation.  [Available here.](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/61126F.pdf)  It gives you the gory details of actually controlling the USB functions through the PIC. It also refers you to details in the USB specifications.

A quick run through shows the actual electrical connection to be rather trivial - unless the pins of the PIC are located more than just a few millimeters from the pins of the USB connector.  In that case, you get to take a "quick" lesson in designing impedance matched PCB traces and RF design.

Once you have things electrically connected, you get to deal with the software side and with the regulatory side (USB IDs, and intellectual property concerns if you are making a commercial product.)

---

I wish you luck.  You're going to need it, and a whole **lot** of perseverance to reach a point where you can successfully implement your own USB device.

Answer (score 1):

USB data pins are not 5V, if the micro has 3V3 USB pins they can be directly connected.